# Which is the best way to migrate data from redis to microsoft azure

Tags: java, redis, data-migration, azure-table-storage

I have thousands of devices running on field which are sending their location data every minute. We are now planning to use Microsoft Azure Table and Redis and as a poc i am storing only 10 devices location data in redis by creating keys for every quarter in an hour per imei, 
like redis key for data send at 23-03-2017 15:01 for imei "abc" will be "abc2017032315Q1".

Expiry time for every Redis key is set to 2 hour.
Now i have to move this data to microsoft azure table for which i am planning to write a job which will read data from redis for last one hour and store it into the Microsoft Azure Table, what will be the best way of migration as i will have to do the same for all thousands of devices. 

I am using Java.

Answer (score 1):

I believe migrating Redis compatible RDB files should work since the RDB files can be exported and Imported back to any deployment environment of Redis.
For more information you can follow link
[RDB](https://rdb.fnordig.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to migrate redis data of last one hour to Azure Table Storage. As I known, there is not any existing tool to support transfering data from redis to Azure Table Storage. So the only way is to build a job using Azure Storage SDK for Java & Jedis to do it programmatically.

However, consideration for the redis data size of thousands of devices, the transfer job seems not to be stable & efficient between on-premises and cloud. You can try to use the command `redis-cli --rdb dump.rdb` to backup a rdb file, and create an Azure Redis Cache temporarily and [import the rdb file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-import-export-data) into it, then to run your job as a [web job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/28/executing-java-web-jobs-on-azure/) or on Azure VM to do the transfering operation via Azure Internal network, and finally delete the temporary Redis Cache and other unused resources.

Comment: Thanks for help Peter, i am using azure redis cache only so i think i do not have to create and import the rdb file right ?

Comment: @SouravAgrawal If you just want to directly use Redis on cloud, sure that you don't transfer data.